# Python wx.listctrl scroll position

Tags: python, wxwidgets, clistctrl

I am trying to get a list scrolled at the initial point after an action whose result is the removal of all items and repopulation.

I wanted to get the scroll position recorded and then set back to it but `GetScrollPos` always returns 0 for some reason.

I have been looking over all the `ListCtrl` methods but can't seem to find a way and also noticed `GetScrollPos` is not there but neither does it raise an exception.

Comment: are you sure you provide the right orientation ? `GetScrollPos (int orientation) const `

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got it to work by calculating the bottom item and using `EnsureVisible` on the one above it since `EnsureVisible` always shows an extra item underneath the targeted one if there is any.

Works perfectly and no need for `GetScrollPos` since I'm pretty sure there is no `SetScrollPos`.

```
list_total  = list.GetItemCount()
list_top    = list.GetTopItem()
list_pp     = list.GetCountPerPage()
list_bottom = min(list_top + list_pp, list_total - 1)
list.EnsureVisible((list_bottom - 1))
```

Comment: I believe that `list.EnsureVisible(list.GetItemCount() - 1)` also does the job